# Spacing before a `lgathered` and other `*ed` environments

Tags: math-mode, spacing, mathtools

I have the following situation:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
  \begin{gather*}
  [a,b]=c, \\
  [c,d]=f, \\
  \left.
  \begin{lgathered}
  [a,b]=c, \\
  [c,d]=f, 
  \end{lgathered}
  \right\} \text{some annotation} \\
  [a,b]=c, \\
  [c,d]=f, 
  \end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

which results in the maddening
[image]

We have to cancel the extra space before the `*ed` environment, but also the one that gets put because of the left delimiter, and I don't seem to be able to get it right. Is there a sane way to do this correctly?

Comment: Why does a `\left.` get the delimiter spacing at all, by the way?

Answer (score 4):

The space from `\left.` is `\nulldelimiterspace` so you can set that to 0pt or as here just correct by that amount.

`lgathered` adds a `\,` before alignment, copying an old bug in `gathered` that was fixed last year.  The package probably should be updated to match `amsmath` but you can use `\!` in the meantime so

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
  \begin{gather*}
  [a,b]=c, \\
  [c,d]=f, \\
  \kern-\nulldelimiterspace\left.\!
  \begin{lgathered}
  [a,b]=c, \\
  [c,d]=f, 
  \end{lgathered}
  \right\} \text{some annotation} \\
  [a,b]=c, \\
  [c,d]=f, 
  \end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Updated `mathtools` (about the `\,`) has just been sent off to CTAN.

Answer (score 2):

You can add some negative math kerning before the `\gathered` environment. I would suggest using the `rcases` instead to simplify the code + some (less) negative math kerning. Also, note you don't have to load `amsmath` since `mathtools` does it for you:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

  \begin{gather*}
  [a,b]=c, \\
  [c,d]=f, \\
  \mkern -2.2mu
  \begin{rcases}
  [a,b]=c, \\
  [c,d]=f,
  \end{rcases}
   \text{some annotation} \\
  [a,b]=c, \\
  [c,d]=f,
  \end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]